# How to check variables in URL before executing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This may seem odd, but it's a requirement for a project I'm working on.  I have a MVC view that provides a UI to search a Lucene index.  Once the user inputs something to search on and presses the submit button, the URL looks something like this:

```
http://.../IMS/Demographics?searchTerm=64453&searchDefault=True&page=1&pageSize=10&ascending=True
```

The "searchDefault" variable is Boolean, as is the ascending variable.  However, the searchDefault variable is displayed with a checkboxfor on the search view.  So, if I change "searchDefault=True"  to "searchDefault=True%27B", I get "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code".  The debugger points to the seachDefault checkboxfor as the problem, because I'm trying to shove a string into a Boolean.  Well, I wrote a Catch for that exception in the Search method, so I'm not sure how to validate or remove the erroneous characters before the URL is executed and it hits the controller Search method.  I validate and remove special characters within the Search method, but this error seems to occur earlier.

Any information on how to catch this would be appreciated.  If this type of security issue has a name, I'd like to know that too.  Thank you.

Comment: And where would `%27B` normally come from? Why are you testing this scenario?

Comment: It's not a security issue, per se. Shoving a string into a parameter that's meant for a boolean doesn't do anything other than cause an exception to be raised by the application, which in the context of a web application would result in a 500 server error. However, this has nothing to do with security. It's perfectly valid for a web server to return a 500 error when warranted, and this is one of those situations. If you jack with the querystring params, you get a 500. That's perfectly valid. You don't have to try to somehow catch that an recover.

Comment: Thanks for reading this.  So, adding a "nice" 500 server error page and redirecting to it in the web.config would suffice?  Right now I get the typical yellow exception page with the verbose error message.  The site is being tested by an IBM App Scan tool and this is one of the scenarios it tested and had an issue with, which may get resolved  with a 500 error page.

Comment: You may encrypt the query string parameters in the url if you don't want the user to be aware of the data that is being passed on post backs which is always advisable.